# python: if not this and not that

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I want to write a condition which checks if both variables are False but I'm not sure if what I'm using is correct:

```
if not var1 and not var2: 
     #do something
```

or should it be:

```
if not (var1 and var2):
    #do something
```

Comment: `not var1 and not var2` is equivalent to `not (var1 or var2)`. It's related to boolean logic properties, not really Python specific.

Comment: Fair enough. thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is called [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). `(not A) and (not B)` is equivalent to `not (A or B)`, and `(not A) or (not B)` is equivalent to `not (A and B)`.

Technically, it's very slightly faster to use the latter, e.g. `not (A and B)`, as the interpreter evaluates fewer logical statements, but it's trivial. Use the logical structure that allows you to state the condition as clearly as possible, on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 2):

`if not (var1 and var2)` is equivalent to `if not var1 or not var2` so your conditions are not the same.

Which one is correct depends on your business logic.

Answer (score 2):

The first is what you want. It checks that both variables are `False`. The second only checks that `var1 and var2` is `False`, which means that they are not both `True` simultaneously; one could be `True` and the other `False`, and the second `if` would return `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is equivalent to

```
if not any((var1, var2)): ...
```

and your second is equivalent to

```
if not all((var1, var2)): ...
```

Those variants might represent the underlying problem better.

If they do, use those.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first example, it's more Pythonic.

Also, your second example is flawed. It will fail if 1 of your variables are True, and the other False.